# Steps for Git branching & merging for 2 developers

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

This is the first time I am using Git Hub. So please co-operate with me.

I am working on an iOS project with another developer. Now since we are working on 2 different functionalities, I thought making separate branches for each developer is good way. So my plan in to follow below steps

1. Create a local branches named `functionality1` from the current one using

   ```
   git checkout -b functionality1
   ```
2. Commit my code in `functionality1` branch
3. Push that branch to the remote using

   ```
   git push origin functionality1
   ```

   This will add my branch to remote server. I need branches on remote because I can work from anywhere.
4. I will merge it in Master branch using

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge functionality1
   ```
5. Now `functionality1` is merged into `master` branch (provided no conflicts occurred)

Other developer will follow same steps.
We don't want to delete the branches yet.

Now once both branches are merged into `master`, how can each developer will get the merged code from `master` branch into their respective branches (`functionality1` & `functionality2`) & then continue on working on same branch (`functionality1` & `functionality2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you shouldn't unless you *really* need the new functionality. Because by merging e.g. `master` back into `functionality1` you make it dependend upon the other feature branch. A good read is the [`gitworkflows(7)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) man-page.